# ORACLE APEX - Set up a Button to populate a textfield

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a button which I would like to take the Input text field called `P7_INPUT` and Divide (`/`) it by `2000` and pop it into the `P7_OUTPUT`

Users enters say `3000` into `P7_INPUT` field and pressed the Button then in the `P7_OUTPUT` is will show the value of `1.5`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the :P7_INPUT and select Create Dynamic Action. Set the following properties:

```
Event: Key Release
Selection Type: Items(s)
Item: P7_INPUT
```

Right-click the dynamic action and select either Create TRUE Action. Set the following properties:

```
Action: Set Value
Set Type: PL/SQL expression 
PL/SQL expression : NVL(:P7_INPUT,0) / 2000
Items to Submit: P7_INPUT
Affected Elements > Selection Type: Item(s)
Affected Elements > Item(s): P7_OUTPUT
```

Comment: Hi Imran, I have tried this solution and it does the required calculation perfectly. Can this be edited if have P7_INPUT a date picker, and want to show the result in P7_OUTPUT (TEXT Field) of P7_INPUT minus current date (current_date)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a button.

- create `P7_INPUT` as a text item; set its "Submit when enter pressed" property to YES
- create `P7_OUTPUT`
- create a **process** which will contain a PL/SQL code:

  ```
  :P7_OUTPUT := :P7_INPUT / 2000;
  ```

That's all; when you enter e.g. 3000 into the input item and press enter, process will do the calculation and display the result in the output item.

If it must be with a button, create it and let it submit the page. Process will look the same, you'd just put `P7_BUTTON` into process' "Server side condition's" "When button pressed" property.

Answer (score 1):

Since you require the action to occur dynamically when the user clicks a button, I would create a Dynamic Action on button click with a **Set Value** action for `P7_OUTPUT` set to a JavaScript expression:

```
parseFloat($v("P7_INPUT)) / 2000
```

This avoids a server round-trip.