# Getting the days difference in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I am very new to Oracle Apex/PLSQL and have built basic application by editing the templates provided in Apex.

My question is that I have a form which saves data into one table. One date field on the form is "Due Date" where the user selects a future date. I have another text field (disabled) named DAYS REMAINING where I want to show DUE DATE - TODAY'S Date (number of days only, no time). I have added a new column in the backend table with same name (DAYS REMAINING) and number data type. In the DAYS REMAINING textbox's "value" section, I have tried calculating days difference by using SELECT DUE DATE (column) - CURRENT_DATE but the result is error.

Could someone advise a simple work around for getting the number of days on the form. The form ultimately saves the data to table.

Comment: What was the error?  Does your `SELECT` statement have a `FROM` clause that you're omitting?  Are you assigning the value to a page item?  Are you doing a `SELECT INTO`?

Comment: This may help you with your processing, but your exact syntax is going to help http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/10/apex-101-dynamic-actions.html

Comment: What i actually want is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327932/oracle-apex-set-up-a-button-to-populate-a-textfield the difference is that i want to perform a calculation on dates (DUE DATE minus Current Date) and get the result in number of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APEX EXAMPLE CREATED:
[image]

---

### [image]

UPDATED Answer based on comments:

Ensure you use Items to Submit and Items to Return fields.

Use a query similar to the following in your dynamic Action:

```
SELECT ROUND(TO_DATE(:P1_DUE_DATE)-SYSDATE) INTO :P1_DAYS_REMAINING FROM DUAL;
```

---

OLD Fiddles:

1. [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f3267/42/0)
2. [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be19cd/6/0)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. Either i failed to do this in correct way or I have not explained  the scenario properly. Please have a look on the below step wise information.

Comment: Hi Aaron, Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. Either i failed to do this in correct way or I have not explained  the scenario properly. Please have a look on the below step wise information. (Step 1). I have created three columns in a table using SQL Workshop. Columns are named 1. Due Date 2. Current Date (2) Days Remaining. (Step 2) Formats of Due Date and Current Date columns is set to be DATE whereas Days Remaining Column's Format is VARCHAR2.

Comment: (Step 3) I have a form where I have 1 Text Field (disabled for edit, shows current date to user by using PL/SQL Expression of current_date), and 1 Date Picker (named Due Date)  where user selects a future date.

Comment: (Step 4) I have added another Text Field, named Days Remaining, here i want to show the user the difference of the days between Due Date and Current Date. Lets say, if current date is 14-Sep-20 and User has selected 20-Sep-20 in due date then the value in DAYS REMAINING text field should be changed to "6 Days". Once user submits the form, the value 6 should be saved to Days Remaining column in the table present at the backend.

Comment: "Columns are named 1. Due Date 2. Current Date (2) Days Remaining" You have columns with spaces in their name? Does not sound correct. Perhaps you have NULL entries. I will create a new fiddle with table with a similar setup to what you describe. Perhaps you could update your Question with your table create script? ALSO - you should really make your days remaining a number column NOT a string

Comment: Created an actual APEX example and updated answer with the details and link